# How to use Cloud-init to create an Ubuntu 20 server with a specific disk size?

Tags: virtualization, disk, cloud-init

How to set the initial **disk size** for Ubuntu 20 virtual servers provisioned by Cloud-init, when self hosting?

I've been researching cloudinit [docs](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html?highlight=layout#disk-setup), but I'm not seeing the option to set the disk size.  The Cloud-init disk **size** property looks badly named as the docs describe the property as the **percentage of overall disk space** that the partition will occupy. So size 30 will make a partition 30% of total disk.

Also the docs mention in may places about resizing filesystems to 100% of disk on first boot, but I don't see how to specify that initial disk size, for that partition to resize into.

Is Cloud-init intended role only after some other process has created the initial disks?

My use case is to automate the creation of Ubuntu 20 virtual servers that I am self hosting. Something that I have been doing successfully for years with a combination of Virtualbox and custom shell scripts.  IMHO Cloud-init framework adds complexity without clear benefits for simple home installations. Logically there must be a scaling point where the investment in time and effort using Cloud-init starts to pay back that debt. So I am attempting to embrace the system provisioning framework that is bundled with Ubuntu. There seems to be lots of cool features like creating users, resizing disks on first boot. The system just needs to be provisioned larger at the start. Sure I could add additional disk to the system, but that adds extra management for backups etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Cloud-init intended role only after some other process has created
> the initial disks?

yes - that is the case.
Cloud init runs "*inside*" the guest, it can not change the actual disk size that is provided. It can only affect to what amount the Filesystem on it will consume the disk.

Workflow order:

1. On the **Host** a tool creates a qcow image file of some size
   (usually you'd have a cloud-image and make the new file a COW-clone, for
   initial deployment speed; depending on the Pro-grade you can go more complex
   as needed but this solution works fine)
2. When the **guest** starts cloud-init helps to customize that to differentiate
   it from the other thousands of times you instantiate from the same image. As
   part of this (the default) it extends the FS on the disk to 100% of the disk
   size as that is what is wanted in most cases (or to the percentage you set, if
   100% isn't what you need)..

To change the disk size of various guests created, you'll have to create different sizes in step #1 at the host.

If you want you can take a look at [uvtool](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Euvtool-dev/uvtool/+git/uvtool/+ref/master) which does both above steps to learn more about it.

P.S. If you thought about cloud-init more like an installer ... that is [curtin](https://readthedocs.org/projects/curtin/). But to be clear - in a virtual environment that still couldn't change the size of the actual disk - that will always be at the hypervisor level providing said disk.